# Difficulty aligning divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, alignment

There are a number of similar topics, but none of the ones I looked at have helped me solve the problem I've encountered. Basically, I have a set of tabs that I want to be aligned in the center of my page. Unfortunately, they appear slightly left of center, which looks absolutely terrible. Maybe I missed something obvious, but after poking around with the code for almost an hour, I'm starting to think the issue is a little more complex.

I prepared a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NTY5/

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">The tabs below should line up with this text.</div>
<br/>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <ul class="_t_ul">
        <li class="_t_li">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="_t_li">Tab 2</li>
        <li class="_t_li">tab 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="text-align:center;">As you can see, it isn't even close.</div>

 ._t_ul {

    line-height:33px;

    list-style:none;

}

._t_li {

    display: inline;

    cursor:pointer;

    text-align:center;

    color: #698da5;

    font-family:'Anton', sans-serif;

    font-size: 14px;

    font-weight:bold;

    text-align:center;

    padding:16px;

    background-color: rgba(82%, 82%, 82%, 0.5);

    border: 1px solid #acadaf;

    border-radius: 4px;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

}

._t_li:hover {

    background-color: rgba(82%, 82%, 82%, 0.8);

}
```

Also, I was able to get it to align properly using inline elements, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do with block (such as li and div).

Comment: it's centered in my browser , you want centering it vertically ?

Comment: Here's what it looks like in my browser: http://i.imgur.com/BkXpk8G.png. Can you post a screenshot of yours?

Answer (score 1):

```
._t_ul {
   padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 33px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to align the tabs alone to the horizontal centre, use this line of code on the div in which the tabs are nested.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

If you're looking to align the tabs to the left edge of the text, use the same value of margin-left for both the divs.

This is all assuming you've cleaned up the default margin and padding the browser sets on the li and ul at the beginning of the document.

```
li, ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, try using `margin-right:auto; margin-left: auto` and setting a fixed width to the tabs instead of just applying `text-align:center`.

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eshellborn/SASSe/